# Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CanvasImageSource'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get the same image to load into all of the canvas in my HTML. I had previously written my whole webpage in javascript but now I am learning angular and typescript.

I am getting this error highlighted in Visual Studio Code:

> Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CanvasImageSource'.
>     Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLVideoElement': height, msHorizontalMirror, msIsLayoutOptimalForPlayback, msIsStereo3D, and 80 more.ts(2345)

But I get no error shown in the console. I can get the image to load on the HTML within the canvas (so it is working).

This is my ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    document.querySelectorAll("canvas").forEach(c=>{
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("P43");
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,106,50); //(image, offsetx, offsety, x, y)
    });
  }

}
```

VS Code highlights the error on this line `ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,106,50); //(image, offsetx, offsety, x, y)`, it highlights **img** and displays the error.

I have tried to search this but the only solutions I have found are for when you had the ID for tag ( I don't as it is all canvas' on the page.) or if there is an input.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the element with id P43 a canvas or image element?

Comment: You need to narrow the type of the `img` with a type guard or cast it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler that the `img` variable is being set as an `HTMLImageElement`.

The `ctx.drawImage` method expects a :

```
HTMLOrSVGImageElement | HTMLVideoElement | HTMLCanvasElement | ImageBitmap;
```

If your `P43` is a canvas you have to do:

```
const img = document.getElementById("P43") as HTMLCanvasElement;
```

if it's an image element:

```
const img = document.getElementById("P43") as HTMLImageElement;
```

---

It would be even better to actually check that the element is in fact the right type of `Element`. You can do this with `instanceof`. The TypeScript compiler will also pick up the if statement, and inside the if statement the `img` variable will be a `HTMLCanvasElement` for the compiler, so explicit casting is no longer necessary:

```
const img = document.getElementById("P43");

if (img instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,106,50);
} else {
  // wrong element!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell the TS compiler the specific types of HTML elements that you are using in your component.

Here you are querying the document object and getting some     element and calling some methods on those elements. Since TypeScript     is unable to infer the types of these element and hence producing compiler errors, the Type need to be explicitly stated.

Try this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    document.querySelectorAll('canvas').forEach((c: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
      const ctx =  <CanvasRenderingContext2D> c.getContext('2d');
      const img = <HTMLImageElement> document.getElementById('P43');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 106, 50);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you were unable to use `as HTMLImageElement` you can use this syntax to cunstruct image as needed, it worked for me:

```
var img = new Image(); // Image constructor
img.src = 'image.png';
img.alt = 'alt';
```

Then you can use:

```
 ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

Src:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#example